# How to create Actions(Buttons, Links, and Actions) that opens visualforce page in same window and not as modal?

Tags: lightning

By default clicking on an Action(Visualforce Page) opens the page in Modal. However in Salesforce CPQ, clicking on 'Edit Line Items' action on Quote opens a visualforce page in same window.

How do we do it? How to create Actions(Buttons, Links, and Actions) that opens visualforce page in same window and not as modal?

Comment: The action triggered from CPQ is being triggered from another custom code with which you can configure how the resulting page should open. With standard action, I don't think we have such a granularity.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create an 'Action'.

Create a 'Detail Page Button' and select 'Display in existing Window without sidebar'. Select Content Source as 'Visualforce Page'. This will create both - A button and 'Mobile and Lightning Experience Action'.

Then go to Page Layout and do not add 'Custom Button' to Page Layout, instead add 'Mobile and Lightning Experience Action' to 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions' section.

This will open the custom Visualforce page in the same window.